# Sierpinski Triangle in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fractals

I have written the following code but I seem to be missing something and I'm not sure what it is:

```
axis off

hold on

for i = 1:10000

    r = [rand() rand()];

    rp = [(1 - sqrt(r(1))) * -1 + (sqrt(r(1)) * (1 - r(2))) * 0 + (sqrt(r(1)) * r(2)) * 1,
        (1 - sqrt(r(1))) * 0 + (sqrt(r(1)) * (1 - r(2))) * sqrt(3) + (sqrt(r(1)) * r(2)) * 0];

    v1 = [-1 0 1];
    v2 = [0 sqrt(3) 0];
    num = randi([1 3], 1);
    rv = [v1(num) v2(num)];

    mid_x = (rp(1) + rv(1))/2;
    mid_y = (rp(2) + rv(2))/2;
    plot(mid_x, mid_y, '.r', 'MarkerSize', 0.000001)

end
```

this is what I'm getting instead:

triangle

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: What is wrong? What were you expecting? You’ve got to be explicit here. We really don’t know what is wrong because the figure you posted is exactly what the code describes. Thus, you coded something different than what you wanted to code, but we cannot look in your mind and guess what you wanted to code.

Comment: If you want more layers of the Sierpinski triangle then you need to add another loop, within the loop scale the current point by `sqrt(3)` and add another random `rv`. The more times you repeat this loop, the more levels of the fractal you’ll get.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues:

1. You've reset `r` to a random value each time through the loop and *then* performed a computation that puts it in one of the three sub-triangles that appear in your image. Rather than doing that, you should redefine `r` each time in terms of its previous value. That's the basic idea behind iteration in general.
2. I'm not sure what the computation involving the square root is for. The basic computation for a Sierpinski triangle simply moves the current point `r` half the way to one of the three vertices of the triangle, which is randomly chosen. That's correctly done in your definition of `mid_x` and `mid_y`.

Taking this all into account, we get something that looks like so:

```
axis off
hold on
r = [rand() rand()];          % Define initial value of r outside the loop
v1 = [-1 0 1];
v2 = [0 sqrt(3) 0];
for i = 1:10000
    num = randi([1 3], 1);
    rv = [v1(num) v2(num)];
    mid_x = (r(1) + rv(1))/2;
    mid_y = (r(2) + rv(2))/2;
    r = [mid_x mid_y];        % Redefine r each time through the loop
    plot(mid_x, mid_y, '.r', 'MarkerSize', 0.000001)
end
```

[image]

Comment: You can write `r = [rand() rand()];`  as `r=rand(1,2);`

Comment: @SardarUsama True that! I was trying to stick closely to the original code, however.

Comment: Thanks @MarkMcClure that was a great help. The computation involving the square root was to make sure only points within the triangle were picked but I guess that wasn't necessary.

Comment: @SardarUsama I hadn't thought of that but I will use it thank you.